# Select row pair based on a value of next line R

Tags: r, subset, criteria

I have a df which looks sth like this:

```
ID   value
1     A
2     C
3     A
4     B
5     C
6     B
7     A
8     B
```

I need to get a subset of paired rows where the first row has a value A and is followed by row which has a value B. Result should look like this:

```
ID  value
3    A
4    B
7    A
8    B
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, we can use `lag` and `lead` to get previous and next values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  filter(value == "A" & lead(value) == "B" | value == "B" & lag(value) == "A")

#  ID value
#1  3     A
#2  4     B
#3  7     A
#4  8     B
```

Similarly in `data.table`, we can use `shift` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[value == "A" & shift(value, type = "lead") == "B" | 
          value == "B" & shift(value) == "A"]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, value = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my not very elegant solution. I manually iterate through rows using `sapply()`, then I used `ifelse()` to find desired pairs `AB`. So the `A` is in the pair if the next value is `B` but it only gives `TRUE` for rows with `A`, so I made second condition checking whether `B` is in the pair. I was looking of previous value of `B` if it's `A` then we have a pair. As a result I have vector (new column) `res` with `T/F` values. Now all I had to do is to select only rows with `T`. Finally some cosmetic stuff.

```
df$res <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) ifelse((df[x,2]=='A' & df[x+1,2]=='B') | (df[x,2]=='B' & df[x-1,2]=='A'),TRUE,FALSE))
    df <- df[df$res==T,]
    df$res <- NULL
    df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
    df
      ID value
    3  3     A
    4  4     B
    7  7     A
    8  8     B
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.